# ASPxGridView deleting multiple rows with input type checkbox

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a `dx:ASPxGridView` with one input type, checkbox column. When I am deleting from bottom to top one by one it's deleting fine, but when deleting from top to bottom it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
 protected void grdItems_CustomCallback(object sender,     
     DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Parameters.StartsWith("del"))
    {
       var PurchaseCol = grdItems.Columns["Purchase"] as GridViewDataColumn;
        var BoCustomer = BoCustomerPO;
        for (int i = 0; i < grdItems.VisibleRowCount; i++)
        {                      
            var order = (HtmlInputCheckBox)grdItems.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, PurchaseCol, "selectRec");
            if(order.Checked == true)
            {
                string orderID = Convert.ToString(order.Value);

                BOCustomerPOBL.DeletePO(BoCustomerPO, orderID);

                }                                                                   
        }
        BindGrid();
    }


}
```

`FindRowCellTemplateControl`, after deleting one row in this control is finding the deleted row again instead of get the second row.

Answer (score 0):

Grid doesn't know that you deleted row if you are just deleting it from database.  Use  DeleteRow method to delete row, and RowDeleting / RowDeleted event for additional delete processing. 
Also, you could use ASPxgridView selection feature instead of cell template with checkboxes. Here is complete example of deleting multiple ASPxGridView rows:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3711

Read "Deleting Rows" section.